# Unpublished and republished Android App, now it's not available anymore. Does it take some Time?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I unpublished and republished my Google Play Store App, but now it's not available anymore, even though it says "Published" under the availability status. Is that normal? Does it take some time? Thanks for any helpful reply!

Comment: Recently google increased their review time. It might be due to that. [source](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-store-approval-new-apps-time/)

Comment: Do they review my app again if I don't change anything to the apk and just un- and republish it? Weird...

Comment: Yes, it will. I have been waiting for 4 days now

Comment: Is it processed now or are you still waiting?

Comment: @Aslam Also see this - https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/04/improving-update-process-with-your.html

Answer (score 0):

Check its available to all countries?

Comment: It is, it also says "update processing" since 2 days, even though I did not upload a new version...